# VSCode Extension Replace Entire Document's text

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I know how to make a builder work with selections, but I can't work out what to put in place of my "something" comment

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(builder => {
    builder.replace(/* something */, "Hello world!");
});
```

The desired result is that the entire active document is replaced with "Hello world!"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The desired result is that the entire active document is replaced with "Hello world!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved like this:

```
vscode.window.activeTextEditor.edit(builder => {
    const doc = vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document;
    builder.replace(new vscode.Range(doc.lineAt(0).range.start, doc.lineAt(doc.lineCount - 1).range.end), "Hello world!");
});
```